# How to solve *7 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown"?

Tags: php, nginx

This error is returned whenever the `fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock` is requested:

```
[error] 10910#10910: *7 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /api/user.php HTTP/2.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost"
```

This is what the `access.log` looks like:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jun/2023:15:57:33 +0200] "GET /api/user.php HTTP/2.0" 404 16 "-" "curl/7.88.1"
```

This is my related nginx configuration:

```
pid /path/to/my/directory/nginx.pid;
user seba www-data;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    # HTTP server
    server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name syskeep;

        # Redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    # HTTPS server
    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;

        # Uncomment to let SysKeep public available
        # listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

        server_name localhost;

        root /path/to/my/directory/public/;

        index index.html index.php;

        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;


        # SSL certificate files
        ssl_certificate /path/to/my/directory/localhost.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /path/to/my/directory/localhost-key.pem;

        # SSL configuration
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

        # Add security-related headers
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        add_header Referrer-Policy "strict-origin-when-cross-origin";


        location ^~ /api {
            alias /path/to/my/directory/core/src/public/;
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        }


    }

    types {
        application/javascript js;
        text/css css;
        text/html html;
    }
}
```

If I `curl https://localhost/api/user.php`, this is the response body:

```
File not found.
```

With a 404 HTTP status code

Please note that I'm starting nginx with:

```
# nginx -c /path/to/custom/nginx.conf
```

Comment: Try replacing the `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;` line with `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;`

Comment: @RichardSmith Nothing has canged